# How can I modify the condition of the while loop in the Interpreter class to correctly output the results of the code to the console?

Tags: javascript, while-loop, undefined

**Problem: `runCode` does not produce any output to the console**

I suspect the while loop is checking to see if `programCounter` is less than the length of the `stack` rather than the length of `code`.  Perhaps this would cause an endless loop since `programCounter` will always be less than or equal to the length of the stack.

Here's my code:

```
const STOP = 'STOP';
const ADD = 'ADD';
const PUSH = 'PUSH'; 
const MUL = 'MUL';
const DIV = 'DIV';
const SUB = 'SUB';
const LT = 'LT';
const GT = 'GT';
const EQ = 'EQ';
const AND = 'AND';
const OR = 'OR';

class Interpreter {
    constructor() {
        this.state = {
            programCounter: 0,
            stack: [],
            code: []
        };
    }

    runCode(code) {
        this.state.code = code;

        while(this.state.programCounter < this.state.stack.length) {
            const opCode = this.state.code[this.state.programCounter];

            try {
              switch (opCode) {
                case STOP:
                  throw new Error('Execution complete');
              case PUSH:
                  this.state.programCounter++;
                  const value = this.state.code[this.state.programCounter];
                  this.state.stack.push(value);
                  break;
                case ADD:
                case SUB:
                case MUL:
                case DIV:
                case LT:
                case GT:
                case EQ:
                case AND:
                case OR:
                  const a = this.state.stack.pop();
                  const b = this.state.stack.pop();

                  let result;

                  if (opCode === ADD) result = a + b;
                  if (opCode === SUB) result = a - b;
                  if (opCode === MUL) result = a * b;
                  if (opCode === DIV) result = a / b;
                  if (opCode === LT) result = a < b ? 1 : 0;
                  if (opCode === GT) result = a > b ? 1 : 0;
                  if (opCode === EQ) result = a == b ? 1 : 0;
                  if (opCode === AND) result = a && b;
                  if (opCode === OR) result || b;
                

                  this.state.stack.push(result);
                  break;
              default:
                  break;
              }
            } catch (error) {
              return this.state.stack[this.state.stack.length-1];
            }

            this.state.programCounter++;
        }
    }
}

// Create a new instance of the Interpreter class
const interpreter = new Interpreter();

// Define the code to be executed
let code = [PUSH, 2, PUSH, 3, ADD, STOP];

// Run the code and assign the result to a variable
let result = interpreter.runCode(code);

// Output the result to the console
console.log('Result of 3 ADD 2:', result);

// Define and run additional code
code = [PUSH, 2, PUSH, 3, SUB, STOP];
result = interpreter.runCode(code);
console.log('Result of 3 SUB 2:', result);

code = [PUSH, 2, PUSH, 3, MUL, STOP];
result = interpreter.runCode(code);
console.log('Result of 3 MUL 2:', result);

code = [PUSH, 2, PUSH, 3, DIV, STOP];
result = interpreter.runCode(code);
console.log('Result of 3 DIV 2:', result);

code = [PUSH, 2, PUSH, 3, DIV, STOP];
result = interpreter.runCode(code);
console.log('Result of 3 LT 2:', result);

code = [PUSH, 2, PUSH, 3, DIV, STOP];
result = interpreter.runCode(code);
console.log('Result of 3 GT 2:', result);
```

Here's the terminal output:
[image: terminal output]

My expectations were to see the following:

```
Result of 3 ADD 2: 5
Result of 3 SUB 2: 1
Result of 3 MUL 2: 6
Result of 3 DIV 2: 1.5
Result of 3 LT 2: 0
Result of 3 GT 2: 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Your Interpreter is very close to running nicely in terms of implementation. There are a few fixes though.

Notice how there's no need to increase `programCounter` in the `PUSH` case. You just need to add one unit inside the brackets since you already increment it in the last line of the loop.

```
case PUSH: 
    const value = this.state.code[this.state.programCounter + 1];
    this.state.stack.push(value);
    break;
```

In addition, it's needed to reset the counter each time you call `runCode`. The fix is simple, just put it right below the function declaration.

```
runCode(code) {
    this.state.programCounter = 0;
...
}
```

Regarding the loop, just make sure you use `code` instead of `stack` because the former acts as the iteration counter. This is,

```
while (this.state.programCounter < this.state.code.length)
```

Lastly, remember to change `DIV` to `LT` and `GT` in later lines.

```
code = [PUSH, 2, PUSH, 3, LT, STOP]; // not DIV
code = [PUSH, 2, PUSH, 3, GT, STOP]; // not DIV
```

As seen in the following working example.

```js
const STOP = 'STOP';
const ADD = 'ADD';
const PUSH = 'PUSH';
const MUL = 'MUL';
const DIV = 'DIV';
const SUB = 'SUB';
const LT = 'LT';
const GT = 'GT';
const EQ = 'EQ';
const AND = 'AND';
const OR = 'OR';

class Interpreter {
  constructor() {
    this.state = {
      programCounter: 0,
      stack: [],
      code: [],
    };
  }

  runCode(code) {
    this.state.programCounter = 0;
    this.state.code = code;

    while (this.state.programCounter < this.state.code.length) {
      const opCode = this.state.code[this.state.programCounter];

      try {
        switch (opCode) {
          case STOP:
            throw new Error('Execution complete');
          case PUSH:
            const value = this.state.code[this.state.programCounter + 1];
            this.state.stack.push(value);
            break;
          case ADD:
          case SUB:
          case MUL:
          case DIV:
          case LT:
          case GT:
          case EQ:
          case AND:
          case OR:
            const a = this.state.stack.pop();
            const b = this.state.stack.pop();

            let result;

            if (opCode === ADD) result = a + b;
            if (opCode === SUB) result = a - b;
            if (opCode === MUL) result = a * b;
            if (opCode === DIV) result = a / b;
            if (opCode === LT) result = a < b ? 1 : 0;
            if (opCode === GT) result = a > b ? 1 : 0;
            if (opCode === EQ) result = a == b ? 1 : 0;
            if (opCode === AND) result = a && b;
            if (opCode === OR) result || b;

            this.state.stack.push(result);
            break;
          default:
            break;
        }
      } catch (error) {
        return this.state.stack[this.state.stack.length - 1];
      }

      this.state.programCounter++;
    }
  }
}

// Create a new instance of the Interpreter class
const interpreter = new Interpreter();

// Define the code to be executed
let code = [PUSH, 2, PUSH, 3, ADD, STOP];

// Run the code and assign the result to a variable
let result = interpreter.runCode(code);

// Output the result to the console
console.log('Result of 3 ADD 2:', result);

// Define and run additional code
code = [PUSH, 2, PUSH, 3, SUB, STOP];
result = interpreter.runCode(code);
console.log('Result of 3 SUB 2:', result);

code = [PUSH, 2, PUSH, 3, MUL, STOP];
result = interpreter.runCode(code);
console.log('Result of 3 MUL 2:', result);

code = [PUSH, 2, PUSH, 3, DIV, STOP];
result = interpreter.runCode(code);
console.log('Result of 3 DIV 2:', result);

code = [PUSH, 2, PUSH, 3, LT, STOP];
result = interpreter.runCode(code);
console.log('Result of 3 LT 2:', result);

code = [PUSH, 2, PUSH, 3, GT, STOP];
result = interpreter.runCode(code);
console.log('Result of 3 GT 2:', result);
```